# Configure APT to use a specific IP address or network interface

Tags: networking, apt

I have a situation where a server has two IP addresses, both assigned to the same interface. How can I tell APT to use a specific IP to download packages and update caches?

Basically I'm looking for something like `--interface` in `curl(1)`, only for APT.

```
     --interface <name>

          Perform an  operation using a specified  interface. You
          can enter interface  name, IP address or  host name...
```

I've looked into `apt.conf(5)` and `apt-transport-http(1)` and found no options there.

I have in mind two workarounds:

1. Setup a proxy that is aware of different interfaces/IPs, and use `Acquire::http::Proxy` to tell APT to go through that.
2. Perhaps I can setup some network namespaces to achieve this, although I've yet to dive into the docs.

Is it possible for APT to use a specific network interface/IP address? If not, what would be a better workaround?

Here's the specifics of the situation:

A server is assigned two IP addresses, each of which is behind a NAT to the Internet. (The bridge here is only for ease of configuration management, and actually only `enp1s0` is behind `br0`.)

```
$ ip address show br0
9. br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 1055sec preferred_lft 1055sec
    inet 192.168.0.3/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global secondary br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5867:78ff:fef8:7146/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The two IPs are NAT'ed behind different public IPs. One of them (`192.168.0.3`) has a high bandwidth to the Internet and is desired for downloading APT packages. However, almost all the other network connections should go through the other IP, and so it (`192.168.0.2`) is set in the default route.

The desired effect is for APT to use `192.168.0.3` to download packages and caches.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that you have more than one interface that can route towards the update servers, what you need to make sure a route is chosen towards a given set of IP addresses (your update servers) is **Policy Routing**.

Here's a blog post that discusses something that I think is similar to what you need: https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2019/03/linux-policy-based-routing/